# HTA/VBScript specific file download error possibly due to size

Tags: vbscript, download, xmlhttprequest, hta

I've been trying to figure out this issue for 3 days now and I want to hurt myself.

I built a little utility to download files from a server. The script simply loops through a list of user-entered serials and appends each into the file url. It seems to perform fine for the most part until it hits a large file. "Large" being the third serial which is the one and only test case of 500mb I've encountered. The first two are less than 20mb. The smaller files download fine, but the larger file throws a "Not enough memory resources are available to complete this operation." error. I have 16gb of ram (barely utilized) and more than enough storage space.

Here's the really strange part, if I only attempt to download the 500mb file (enter only the last serial), sometimes it works. I cannot conclude what the cause is.

I've included a heavily stripped version of my code. I thought pulling pieces out might resolve the issue or at least shed some light, but it persists. I'd be grateful to anyone that can help me resolve this.

To recreate, copy my script below into a text file and rename extension from .txt to .hta. To use, enter the 3 serials below (including commas) into the text box and click download. The script creates the directory "C:\Downloads" and places downloaded files within:

Serials:

BLES01294,BCES00510,BLUS30109

My hta script:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- saved from url=(0014)about:internet -->
<html style="display: inline-block;" id="mainHTML">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=9"/>

<title>Download Tool</title>
<!--Styles defined for doc (end)-->
<!--Scripts to control app window size, position, and behavior (start)-->

<script language="VBScript">

    window.resizeTo 500,300
    screenWidth = document.parentwindow.screen.availwidth
    screenHeight = document.parentwindow.screen.availheight
    posLeft = (screenWidth - 800) / 2
    posTop = (screenHeight - 600) / 2     
    window.moveTo posLeft, posTop

</script>
<!--Scripts to control app window size, position, and behavior (end)-->
<!--Features of app window (start)-->
<HTA:APPLICATION ID="download tool"
    APPLICATIONNAME="download tool
    version="ver.2020.4.13"
    CAPTION="yes"
    BORDER="thin"
    BORDERSTYLE="none"
    ICON=""
    CONTEXTMENU="yes"
    MAXIMIZEBUTTON="no"
    MINIMIZEBUTTON="yes"
    NAVIGABLE="no"
    SCROLL="no"
    SCROLLFLAT="no"
    SELECTION="no"
    SHOWINTASKBAR="yes"
    SINGLEINSTANCE="yes"
    SYSMENU="yes"
    WINDOWSTATE="normal">
</head>
<!--Features of app window (end)-->
<body style="display: inline-block;" id="mainBody" >
    <div id="Menu" style="display: inline;"><br>

        <center>
        <span style="display:inline-block;" id="Span_APIText">
            <center>
                <Span style="display: inline-block;">
                    <span  >
                        <textarea style="width:70%;" class="apitextarea" name="txtPS3SerialEntry" rows=6 id="txtPS3SerialEntry"/></textarea>
                    </span>
                    <span id="Span_Buttons2" style="display: inline-block;">
                            <br><br><button id="GetGameDataBtn" title="Browse for download directory" onclick="dataValidation()"><br>Download</button>
                    </span>
                </span>
            </center>
        </span>
        </center>

        </div>
    </div>
</body> 
</html>

<script language="VBScript">

'=================================================
Function dataValidation()

'on error resume next

noBlanks = ""

    EntryTest = trim(ucase(document.getelementbyID("txtPS3SerialEntry").value))

    if EntryTest = "" then
        alert "No valid API numbers found in list"
        exit function

    elseif EntryTest <> "" then
        document.getelementbyID("txtPS3SerialEntry").value = replace(EntryTest,",",vblf)
        chkBlankLines = split(document.getelementbyID("txtPS3SerialEntry").value,vblf)
    else
        chkBlankLines = split(document.getelementbyID("txtPS3SerialEntry").value,vblf)
    end if

    for i = 0 to Ubound(chkBlankLines)
        If Len(trim(chkBlankLines(i))) > 0 then
            noBlanks = noBlanks & chkBlankLines(i) & vbcrlf
        End If
    Next 

    if noBlanks = "" then
        alert "No valid API numbers found in list"
        exit function
    Else
        document.getelementbyID("txtPS3SerialEntry").value = trim(noBlanks)
    End If

    chkNumeric = split(document.getelementbyID("txtPS3SerialEntry").value,vblf)

    call getFiles()

end function

'========================================================

Sub ccSleep(seconds)
    set oShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
    cmd = "%COMSPEC% /c ping -n " & 1 + seconds & " 127.0.0.1>nul"
    oShell.Run cmd,0,1
End Sub

'============================================================

Function ConvertSize(byteSize) 
    dim Size
    Size = byteSize

    Do While InStr(Size,",") 'Remove commas from size 
        CommaLocate = InStr(Size,",") 
        Size = Mid(Size,1,CommaLocate - 1) & _ 
        Mid(Size,CommaLocate + 1,Len(Size) - CommaLocate) 
    Loop

    Suffix = " Bytes" 
    If Size >= 1024 Then suffix = " KB" 
    If Size >= 1048576 Then suffix = " MB" 
    If Size >= 1073741824 Then suffix = " GB" 
    If Size >= 1099511627776 Then suffix = " TB" 

    Select Case Suffix 
        Case " KB" Size = Round(Size / 1024, 1) 
        Case " MB" Size = Round(Size / 1048576, 1) 
        Case " GB" Size = Round(Size / 1073741824, 1) 
        Case " TB" Size = Round(Size / 1099511627776, 1) 
    End Select

    ConvertSize = Size & Suffix 
End Function

'========================================================================
'Main Function Start
'========================================================================

function GetFiles()

'on error resume next

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
path = "c:\Downloads" 'fso.BuildPath("c:\Downloads","")

If NOT fso.FolderExists(path & "\") then
    fso.CreateFolder(path & "\")
end if

arrStr = split(ucase(document.getelementbyID("txtPS3SerialEntry").value),vbLf)

APICount = Ubound(arrStr)

for i = 0 to Ubound(arrStr)

    API = trim(arrStr(i))

    if API <> "" then

        Set IE = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")
        IE.Visible = false
        IE.Navigate replace("https://a0.ww.np.dl.playstation.net/tpl/np/{game_id}/{game_id}-ver.xml","{game_id}",API)

        Do While IE.Busy or IE.ReadyState <> 4: ccSleep(1): Loop
        Do Until IE.Document.ReadyState = "complete": ccSleep(1): Loop

        on error resume next
            ie.document.getelementbyid("overridelink").click
        on error goto 0

        Do While IE.Busy or IE.ReadyState <> 4: ccSleep(1): Loop
        Do Until IE.Document.ReadyState = "complete": ccSleep(1): Loop

        '============================================================
        id = API

        '============================================================
        'Grab xml elements from site
            for each a in ie.document.getelementsbytagname("package")
                ps3ver = a.getattribute("ps3_system_ver")
                url = a.getattribute("url")
                strFileSize = convertsize(a.getattribute("size"))
                ver = a.getattribute("version")
                strFileName = mid(url,instrrev(url,"/")+1)

                '============================================================

                filename = "c:\Downloads\" & strFileName

                msgbox "Getting file: " & strFileName & " (" & strFileSize & ")"

                Set xHttp = createobject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
                Set bStrm = createobject("Adodb.Stream")

                xHttp.Open "GET", url, false
                xHttp.Send

'on error resume next

                with bStrm
                    .type = 1 '//binary
                    .open
                    .write xHttp.responseBody
                    .savetofile filename, 2 '//overwrite
                    .close
                end with

'on error goto 0

'----------------------------------------------------------------

            Next
    end if

Next 'APICount

ie.quit

end function

'========================================================================
</script>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Command line download large (500+mb) file using vbscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18445890/command-line-download-large-500mb-file-using-vbscript)

Comment: I managed to get it to work with this method for a 500mb file, but now failing with a 1.4 gb file. I might be able to adjust if I understood what was happening in the code you provided. I tried adjusting chunksize higher (for higher gb), but fails. Adjusting it lower let's it get further, but still fails.